# Apache user can't write after chown

Tags: php, apache

I want to allow a directory to be writable by my apache user. I'm using centos 7. Apache user is just `apache`.

From my webroot I've created a write test, and it is returning that the directory is not writable:

/dir/webroot/write-test.php

```
<?php
$filename = 'test';
if (is_writable($filename)) {
    echo 'The file is writable';
} else {
    echo 'The file is not writable';
}
?>
```

When visiting write-test from the browser, I get 'not writable' as the result.

This is the `ls -al` in my `webroot/` dir:

```
drwxr-xr-x.  6 root   root   4096 Jul 22 05:05 .
drwxr-xr-x.  4 root   root     31 Jul 21 18:06 ..
drwxr-xr-x.  2 apache apache    6 Jul 22 05:05 test
-rw-r--r--.  1 root   root    144 Jul 22 05:06 write-test.php
```

Comment: @PaulCrovella Ah, didn't realize it needs to exist as well. I've created the file; the problem persists. I updated my `ls -al`.

Comment: @PaulCrovella Mostly because I'm not familiar with `is_writable()` and I didn't want to worry about whether I was using it wrong so I tried to follow the example in the doc as close as possible. I've updated my post to what I believe is testing the directory.

Answer (score -1):

you can try $filename = '/test.txt';